# Search Array for Best Match based on Day & Time

Tags: php, arrays, date, time

I'm trying to work out how to the the correct Site base on the current Day and Time from an array. The examples array just shows Monday, the real array will contain 7 days of the week with multiple values for each day.

This is the example array :

```
$arr = array (
    array(  'Day' => 'Monday',
            'Start' => '0830',
            'End' => '1730',
            'Site' => 'NW1'),

    array(  'Day' => 'Monday',
            'Start' => '1200',
            'End' => '1300',
            'Site' => 'PL1'),

    array(  'Day' => 'Monday',
            'Start' =>'1730',
            'End' => '2130',
            'Site' => 'RE1')
);
```

So Monday at `1100` I should get `NW1`, at `1800` I should get `RE1`, but between `1200`-`1300` I should get `PL1`

So far this is the code I have:

```
$today = 'Monday'; // Full day name
$time = '1205';

echo "<br/>Day: $today";
echo "<br/>Time: $time <br/><br/>";


$arr = array (
    array(  'Day' => 'Monday',
            'Start' => '0830',
            'End' => '1730',
            'Site' => 'NW1'),

    array(  'Day' => 'Monday',
            'Start' => '1200',
            'End' => '1300',
            'Site' => 'PL1'),

    array(  'Day' => 'Monday',
            'Start' =>'1730',
            'End' => '2130',
            'Site' => 'RE1')
);

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return (date("N", strtotime($a['Day'])) <=> date("N", strtotime($b['Day']))) * 100 +
           ($a['Start'] <=> $b['Start']) * 10 +
           ($a['End'] <=> $b['End']);
});

foreach ($arr as $i => $values) {
    if ($today != $values['Day']) continue;

    if ($time >= $values['Start'] && $time <= $values['End']) {
        $site = $values['Site'];
        break;
    }
}

echo "$today @ $time Site => $site";
```

This works for times between `0830-1730` & `1730-2130`, but not if the time is `1200-1300`.

I'm assuming I need to search the array for the Day match, then the Start time and check the end time, but I'm not sure how to do this  ?

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

**** UPDATE ****
New example array with additional entries

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Day] => Monday
            [Start] => 0830
            [End] => 1730
            [Site] => NW1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Day] => Monday
            [Start] => 0930
            [End] => 0945
            [Site] => PK1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Day] => Monday
            [Start] => 1200
            [End] => 2100
            [Site] => PL1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Day] => Monday
            [Start] => 1230
            [End] => 1245
            [Site] => EM1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Day] => Monday
            [Start] => 1730
            [End] => 2130
            [Site] => RE1
        )
}
```

The expected results are:

```
0940 = PK1
1430 = PL1
0920 = NW1
```

The aim is 0830 to 1730 NW1 is correct unless something else overrides this, ie 1200-2100 PL1 would be correct, after 2100 to 2130 RE1  etc.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't have two entries for NW1?

Comment: Can you explain your `usort` logic?  I don't understand why you're doing multiplication.

Comment: @PatrickQ - I didn't want to have to split the times into multiple entries. There could be 4 or 5 entries per day.  The usort was to reorder the array, I may have go that wrong !

Comment: I was hoping that you could actually explain the logic you are using in the usort so that I could better understand it.  You might be doing it right, you might be doing it wrong.  But unless you explain what you're doing (or at least trying to do), it's hard for me to say which it is.

Comment: "between 1200-1300 I should get PL1" <- why shouldn't you get NW1 as well? It's still monday between 08:30 and 17:30.

Comment: The aim was to sort the array by day and then start time. That way it didn't matter what order they are added to the array they are resorted.

Comment: @jeb - I want 1200-1300 to be the match, other wise the user would have to add `0830->1200`, `1201->1300`, `1301->1730`  That would get really messy if there were 4 or 5 options on a single day. Thanks

Comment: @Rocket  That's the desired outcome, not the logic used to get it.  But whatever, I think you just need to sort by start time _descending_ instead of _ascending_.  That way the latest matched start time gets priority.

Comment: @Rocket Still don't understand what makes PL1 the match over NW1. Say the input is 12:30, is PL1 the match because 1200-1300 is "closer" / more restrictive than 0830-1730? You need to tell us how to determine what takes priority when two entries match.

Comment: If PL1 went to 2130 instead of 1300, would it still be the desired match for 1205?

Comment: @Jeto Sorry I'll try to explain better. On Monday between `0830-1730` the match is `NW1` except if there is a closer match based on the current time.So between `1200-1300` the result would be `PL1` as it is a more precise match

Comment: @PatrickQ yes. that would be the preferred result.

Comment: So all that matters for "best match" is start time, end time doesn't matter?  If that's the case, just do what I said and reverse the start time comparison in your sort logic.

Comment: @PatrickQ are you able to explain how to do that ?

Comment: What if A is 1200-1300, B is 1250-1350 and the input time is 1300? Which one should match then, A or B? Is it B because it's closer to the start time? But then if A is 1100-2200 and B is 1000-1200, should an input of 1100 still match A despite it being a lot wider? Please clarify exactly what you mean by "closer" and preferably so by editing your question (this chain of comments is getting way too long).

Comment: @Jeto - A is 1200-1300, B is 1250-1350, then B is correct, A is 1100-2200 and B is 1000-1200, then B is correct. I'll update the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is reverse the sorting based on start time

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return (date("N", strtotime($a['Day'])) <=> date("N", strtotime($b['Day']))) * 100 +
           ($b['Start'] <=> $a['Start']) * 10 +
           ($a['End'] <=> $b['End']);
});
```

This way, we will loop through the array starting with the latest start time (for each day) and once we find a match, we break the loop, using the site value for the match.

I'm still not really sure of the purpose of the multiplication in your `usort`, but it doesn't seem to be causing any problems, so I'm going to leave it in.

[DEMO](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bwdI)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see as soon as you find a $time between the "start" and "end" you assign the value to $site and then "break" straight away without looking through the rest of the array.

But if the time is 1230 on a Monday which entry in the array should take precedence?

If it is the last one, then maybe hang on to a variable until you search the entire array like so:

```
$lastCorrectEntry;
foreach ($arr as $i => $values) {
    if ($today != $values['Day']) continue;

    if ($time >= $values['Start'] && $time <= $values['End']) {
        $lastCorrectEntry = $values['Site'];
   }
}
$site = $lastCorrectEntry;
```

Comment: Hi. In this example if the time is between 1200-1300 then it should be `PL1`