# Sorting array on multiple values - Day and Time based

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time, days

With some help on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998146/search-array-for-best-match-based-on-day-time) I've go an array that is now sorted and allowing me to return the 
correct values based on Start time.

Simplified the array layout now looks like this:

```
$arr = array (
    array(  'Days' => '1',
            'Start' => '0930',
            'End' => '0945',
            'Site' => 'AA4'),

    array(  'Days' => '12345',
            'Start' => '1200',
            'End' => '1300',
            'Site' => 'EM3'),

    array(  'Days' => '12345',
            'Start' => '0830',
            'End' => '1730',
            'Site' => 'NW1'),

    array(  'Days' => '01',
            'Start' => '1200',
            'End' => '1300',
            'Site' => 'PL1'),

    array(  'Days' => '12345',
            'Start' =>'1730',
            'End' => '2130',
            'Site' => 'RE1')
);
```

The sort is done using:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return (date("N", strtotime($a['Days'])) <=> date("N", strtotime($b['Days']))) * 100 +
           ($b['Start'] <=> $a['Start']) * 10 +
           ($a['End'] <=> $b['End']);
});
```

and the values returned using:

```
foreach ($arr as $i => $values) {
    if (strpos($values['Days'], $today) === false ) continue;

    if ($time >= $values['Start'] && $time <= $values['End']) {
        $site = $values['Site'];
        break;
    }
}

echo "$daysofWeek[$today] @ $time Site => $site";
```

As well as sorting on the start time I need to sort on `Days`. `Sunday = 0`, `Saturday = 6`.

So using the above array example, Monday - Friday (12345) between 0830-1730 the correct site would be `NW1`. 
However between 0930-0945 on Monday only, the site would be `AA4`.

The issue I have is on Sunday & Monday between 1200-1300 the site should be `PL1`, but it matches on `EM3`  There is going be a lot more times/rules added to this, but this is the basic idea.

The aim is to allow users to set the days and times, but then override them if there is a more direct match.

I had thought of adding an additional sort after the current one and sort on the count of the number of values in Days.. but that seems to break the original sort.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

**** UPDATE ****
[Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/273dbbc1602393e35ccac46e458c519e814f0a81) showing what I've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use **array_multisort** like this example for sort with two or more column:

```
array_multisort(array_column($filter_arr, 'Route'), array_column($filter_arr, 'deviceName'),  SORT_ASC, array_column($filter_arr, 'startTime'), SORT_ASC, $filter_arr);
```

Comment: I have tried using this, but always seemed to mess up the previous sort, so while the Days were correct, the Start times were out.

Comment: @Rocket what is going wrong it's  not a correct answers ? Monday @ 1201 Site => PL1

Comment: I'm going to run some additional tests and will let you know how I get on.